# My icons ALL renamed after creating a new folder

Tags: windows-10, desktop

I created a new folder on my desktop, renamed it to random, had a conflict with something in my recycle bin and clicked cancel. After that all my icons on my desktop changed to a variation of `random (number)`. (Random 1-45)

This happened to all 22 of my bats on the desktop including ones in folders (100-125).

How can I fix this? I've been using Windows for years and this is obviously a flaw.

[image: 1]

Comment: Leave a comment, don't be afraid.

Comment: Not sure who. What do you mean random? Like random characters?  Can you post a screen capture so people can see what you are trying to describe? The more information you add to your question the more likely it is someone will see it and have an answer.

Comment: Will do. They quite literally say random(1)-Random(whatever) Ill post it.

Comment: Posted example.

Comment: I can recreate the conflict if needed. And show the windows conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an accidental rename you can simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> to undo it.

You might get lucky and it still be in the history to be able to "undo".

---

Alternatively [System Restore](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/) might be your friend.

- Browse to `C:\Users\<your username>`
- Right click the `Desktop` folder
- In the list select `Restore Previous Versions`

A `Previous Versions` tab will open up in a folder properties window, hopefully one of them contains a "good" version of your Desktop:

[image]

Comment: Tears, wont work, it was a single rename, after doing control Z, it restored only the single folder i was renaming to default. (New Folder).

Comment: This would work in most cases so +1.

Comment: @GabeMarty Added another option by using System Restore, might get lucky there...

Comment: Keep in mind that (unlike Windows 7) the `Restore Previous Versions` function is *not* on by default within a Windows 10 operating system.  You would need to manually configure and enable `File History` to have it available on your local desktop.

Comment: @GabeMarty I've just tested in a newly created folder and the ctrl-z has at least a few steps of history. I don't know how far back or what may cause it to flush history though.

Comment: I don't use system Protector/restore/file history, I find it is tedious and takes up obnoxiously large space. I don't expect windows to oof, only myself, and I have always been able to fix my own issues.

Comment: You guys are all awesome though.

Comment: Will consider question solved, Microsoft says I'm out of luck. Gotta do it all manually -_-.